# remove a mongodb replica set when into a sharding cluster

Tags: cluster, mongodb, sharding

I have this configuration:

```
mongos> db.adminCommand('getShardMap')
{
"map" : {
    "RS13" : "RS13/mongo09-02:27003,mongo09-01:27001",
    "RS13/mongo09-02:27003,mongo09-01:27001" : "RS13/mongo09-02:27003,mongo09-01:27001",
    "RS26" : "RS26/mongo09-04.de.prod:27008,mongo09-01:27002",
    "RS26/mongo09-04.de.prod:27008,mongo09-01:27002" : "RS26/mongo09-04.de.prod:27008,mongo09-01:27002",
    "RS45" : "RS45/mongo09-02:27004,mongo09-03:27005",
    "RS45/mongo09-02:27004,mongo09-03:27005" : "RS45/mongo09-02:27004,mongo09-03:27005",
    "RS67" : "RS67/mongo09-03:27006,mongo09-03.de.prod:27006,mongo09-04.de.prod:27007",
    "RS67/mongo09-03:27006,mongo09-03.de.prod:27006,mongo09-04.de.prod:27007" : "RS67/mongo09-03:27006,mongo09-03.de.prod:27006,mongo09-04.de.prod:27007",
    "config" : "mongo09-01:27011,mongo09-02:27012,mongo09-03:27013",
    "mongo09-01:27001" : "RS13/mongo09-02:27003,mongo09-01:27001",
    "mongo09-01:27002" : "RS26/mongo09-04.de.prod:27008,mongo09-01:27002",
    "mongo09-02:27003" : "RS13/mongo09-02:27003,mongo09-01:27001",
    "mongo09-02:27004" : "RS45/mongo09-02:27004,mongo09-03:27005",
    "mongo09-03.de.prod:27006" : "RS67/mongo09-03:27006,mongo09-03.de.prod:27006,mongo09-04.de.prod:27007",
    "mongo09-03:27005" : "RS45/mongo09-02:27004,mongo09-03:27005",
    "mongo09-03:27006" : "RS67/mongo09-03:27006,mongo09-03.de.prod:27006,mongo09-04.de.prod:27007",
    "mongo09-04.de.prod:27007" : "RS67/mongo09-03:27006,mongo09-03.de.prod:27006,mongo09-04.de.prod:27007",
    "mongo09-04.de.prod:27008" : "RS26/mongo09-04.de.prod:27008,mongo09-01:27002"
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

Actually mongo09-03 it seems to be duplicated:

```
    "mongo09-03.de.prod:27006" : "RS67/mongo09-03:27006,mongo09-03.de.prod:27006,mongo09-04.de.prod:27007",
    "mongo09-03:27006" : "RS67/mongo09-03:27006,mongo09-03.de.prod:27006,mongo09-04.de.prod:27007",
```

And please consider replica set RS67 is also part of a sharding cluster.

May I remove a mongodb replica set when it is into a sharding cluster ?
And if yes, how?

Can I use rs.remove(hostname) ?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't an easy run one command type thing. See the following on the doc site

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/remove-shards-from-cluster/

To remove a replicaset member

```
 rs.remove("mongo09-03.de.prod:27006")
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, I would like to know if I can remove only one host from the replica sets leaving the sharding cluster alive

Comment: yes you can do that. As since there are at least 2 nodes + arbiter in the replicaset.. at least one will contain the data. Then it is as simple as a single command

Comment: Do you know which command? Could we use `db.shards.update({_id: "RS67"} , {$set: {"host" : "RS67/mongo09-03.de.prod:27006,mongo09-04.de.prod:27007"}})` ?

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks Mike, actually waiting I have successfully tried with `db.shards.update...`. Anyway +1 thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

We have successfully configured the replica set executing this command:

```
db.shards.update({_id: "RS67"} , {$set: {"host" : "RS67/mongo09-03.de.prod:27006,mongo09-04.de.prod:27007"}})
```

The shard map now it is correctly configured and extra mongo09-03 has been disappeared.

```
mongos> db.adminCommand('getShardMap') 
{
"map" : {
    "RS13" : "RS13/mongo09-02:27003,mongo09-01:27001",
    "RS13/mongo09-02:27003,mongo09-01:27001" : "RS13/mongo09-02:27003,mongo09-01:27001",
    "RS26" : "RS26/mongo09-04.de.prod:27008,mongo09-01:27002",
    "RS26/mongo09-04.de.prod:27008,mongo09-01:27002" : "RS26/mongo09-04.de.prod:27008,mongo09-01:27002",
    "RS45" : "RS45/mongo09-02:27004,mongo09-03:27005",
    "RS45/mongo09-02:27004,mongo09-03:27005" : "RS45/mongo09-02:27004,mongo09-03:27005",
    "RS67" : "RS67/mongo09-03.de.prod:27006,mongo09-04.de.prod:27007",
    "RS67/mongo09-03.de.prod:27006,mongo09-04.de.prod:27007" : "RS67/mongo09-03.de.prod:27006,mongo09-04.de.prod:27007",
    "config" : "mongo09-01:27011,mongo09-02:27012,mongo09-03:27013",
    "mongo09-01:27001" : "RS13/mongo09-02:27003,mongo09-01:27001",
    "mongo09-01:27002" : "RS26/mongo09-04.de.prod:27008,mongo09-01:27002",
    "mongo09-02:27003" : "RS13/mongo09-02:27003,mongo09-01:27001",
    "mongo09-02:27004" : "RS45/mongo09-02:27004,mongo09-03:27005",
    "mongo09-03.de.prod:27006" : "RS67/mongo09-03.de.prod:27006,mongo09-04.de.prod:27007",
    "mongo09-03:27005" : "RS45/mongo09-02:27004,mongo09-03:27005",
    "mongo09-04.de.prod:27007" : "RS67/mongo09-03.de.prod:27006,mongo09-04.de.prod:27007",
    "mongo09-04.de.prod:27008" : "RS26/mongo09-04.de.prod:27008,mongo09-01:27002"
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

please also consider that:

> The list of hosts in the collection is only used when mongos first
>   starts up, as a seed list. Once the process starts they auto-discover
>   the rest of the members (just like any other client/driver in replica
>   set mode) and keep track of each member in the replica set.